# How do you animate objects coming out of objects realistically?

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I want to create some kind of monster, for a short animation.
The creature should have a long claw hidden in its arm, that comes out when needed, a little like Wolverine.
Modelling isn't the problem, it's a simple, four legged beast, there are no feet, the legs just end more or less plane, protected by armour plating that moves out of the way before the claw extends, so the claw just has to exit through a more or less plane end of the arm. The claw should probably be a separate object, extended by a bone
Now here's my problem
I want the arm to give way for the claw. The claw shouldn't move through the arm object without anything happening, it pierce through the object and shove I aside, like it would in reality.
But I can't figure out how to do that. I tried a rigid body, but the claw just pushed it forward.
Is this even possible?

Comment: have you tried to modify the shape of the mesh with shapekeys?

Comment: @moonboots Yeah, shape keys are an option, but more like the last option if nothing else works. It would mean manually changing the whole mesh of the arm, for every frame. As the purpose of the animation is horror, the claw takes a few seconds, thats, depending on the framerate, hundreds, if not thousands of frames. I'm too lazy for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A softbody could do it. Now I'm far from a specialist in all the softbody knobs, but here is a collision object going through a low poly softbody. Would be better with higher poly I guess and by having the whole basis more rigid.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  It's still a little sticky, not quite perfect, but that can be tweaked. Should work